# Finding the probability of a random graph?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How do I approach this problem? I am new to the topic and I am having a hard time figuring this out.

For Erdos-Renyi graphs on $3$ vertices with parameter p, find the probability
there is an edge between vertices $1$ and $2$ but not between vertices $2$ and $3$.

To find the probability you can use the $$P(G)=p^{m} (1-p)^{{{n}\choose{r}} - m}$$ The question is asking for one edge, so I am guessing that $m = 1$; $n = 3$ and for $p$ I have no idea how to find it. Do I just randomly guess this until I find the probability or is there a way to find it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter p in this model represents the probability each edge is included in the graph, independent from every other edge. So if you are asked to calculate  probability there is an edge between vertices 1 and 2 but not between vertices 2 and 3, p should be given, or you can consider p being given. The information here is not sufficient to find p. Though you are right about m=1 and n=3.